# phpMyAdmin does not open no matter what I change in httpd-xampp.conf

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I just installed xampp and I wanted to open phpMyAdmin.. However, what I get is

> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. etc (Error 403). I have seen many stackoverflow questions on this error but nothing works.This is my httpd-xampp:

```
    #
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php7_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        #Require local
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php7_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        #Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I have set require all granted and allow from all but nothing works. I restart apache on each change but still nothing! All pages in localhost open successfully, but not phpMyAdmin..

Comment: you should be using -vhosts? I've not had to touch any other file to setup pma

Comment: Are you accessing it from the same machine? Xampp has a lockdown in place for `/phpmyadmin` amongst other things near the end of the *httpd-xampp.conf* file (in *apache/conf/extra*)

Comment: @CD001 yes, from the same machine

Comment: Ah just noticed where you've commented out `Require local` ... try changing that to `Require all granted`

Comment: @CD001 I have `Require all granted` on the next line and it's not working

Comment: Oh fffff - sorry, I was looking at the webalizer config block - I'll put my eyes back in.

Comment: I've got a slightly older xampp install so my config is slightly different; but there doesn't appear to be anything there that would bork it on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` ... what happens if you try going to one of the other restricted URLs like `http://localhost/server-status` ?

Comment: @CD001 I can open `http://localhost/server-status` By the way, I restarted my laptop and it is still not working. strange :(

Comment: Yeah - I can't see anything wrong, I was just deliberately breaking the `auth_type` in phpmyadmin's `config.inc.php` file to see if that spaffs out standard 403 errors; it doesn't so it's probably not that either.